# How to get session from Ory Kratos in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, session, cookies

I have not too much experience with Angular and generally web development so this topic is a little bit problematic for me. I am trying to get a session from kratos to authorize an user but I still get some errors. There is my code:

```
this.kratos
  .toSession(undefined, 'Cookie')
  .then(({ data: session }) => {
    // `whoami` returns the session or an error. We're changing the type here
    // because express-session is not detected by TypeScript automatically.
    console.log('SESSION: ' + session);
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // If no session is found, redirect to login.
    console.log('REDIRECTED');
  });
```

There are errors which I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.
Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
http://…3/sessions/whoamiFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 
(Unauthorized)
REDIRECTED
```

There are cookies in my browser:

```
ory_kratos_session  MTYyNjE5MjkwNHxEdi(...)    127.0.0.1
TawkConnectionTime  0                          127.0.0.1
csrf_token          iappKdv+/YcnaJGEPop(...)   127.0.0.1
```

I use the newest version of Ory Kratos and Angular.
The browser is chrome with installed allow CORS addon.